Why Does "this" Behave Differently Inside a Function Called from an Event Listener?
I'm learning JavaScript and struggling with understanding the behavior of "this" in different contexts. I have this piece of code attached to an event listener in a simple web page:
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
console.log(this);
function display() {
console.log(this);
}
display();
});

When I click the button, the first console.log outputs the button element as expected, but the second one inside the display function logs the window object. I was expecting both to log the button since they're in the same outer function. Can someone explain why this changes inside the display function and how to make this in display refer to the button as well?

How to […]: arrow function let display = () => { console.log(this); };. More straightforward, perhaps: let myButton = document.getElementById('myButton'); and refer to myButton instead.
